# Magento Clears Session Data After Redirect

Tags: magento, session

For some reason, Magento clears session or customer session data after redirect? How will I save some data before it redirect to the next page into a session?

I tried adding `session_write_close();` but this doesn't help.

I'm using `Magento::getSingleton('core/session')->setVar('something');` and retrieve it after redirect but it's returning null.

Thank you.

Comment: How you are trying to retrieve from session? Provide that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the session using :

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setVar('something');

and retrieve it using :

$yourSessionVariableValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVar();

Also if you are using caching layers like FPC (Lesti Full page cache module), you need to specify the session variables in backend system->configuration->system